# jQuery or Webkit duplication bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, webkit

I have a small site that takes advantage of a neat scrolling trick and jQuery's .addClass()

Basically, The site checks to see if you've scrolled past a certain point and then sets the class on an element, causing it to have extra transformations or animations.

In Chrome 23.x, There is no issue with the code;
But in Webkit based browsers on Mac, and Chrome 27.x+ (Lowest I've gotten reports of the bug) in other operating systems, The elements "Duplicate" when the class is removed.

The bug has never shown up in Firefox

Here is the Javascript

```
<script>
  $(window).scroll(function () {
      navi = $('#navi').height();
      logo = $('#navi .logo img').height();
      user = $('#user').height();

      if ($(window).scrollTop() >= navi - logo) {
          if (!$('#navi').hasClass("active")) {
              $('#navi').addClass("active");
          }
      } else {
        $('#navi').removeClass("active");
      }
      if ($(window).scrollTop() >= user) {
          if (!$('#user').hasClass("active")) {
              $('#user').addClass("active");
          }
      } else {
        $('#user').removeClass("active");
      }
  });
</script>
```

I'm not 100% that the Javascript is at fault; It may be CSS in Webkit that is causing the issue, either way it is causing me grief.

Here is a [Youtube Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTIb6WPthtk) of the expected results, and here is a [Screenshot](http://gyazo.com/03d1f8e0573c7c2dc29ce647ad5c10c0) of the "Dupe" bug (I run Chrome 23.x in Linux so I had a friend take the screenshot)
The page can be found at **dev.brokengear.net/gatesofender**

Upon further digging, It appears to be an issue with certain browsers artifacting due to it's Tile-Based rendering system.

Comment: I'm unable to repro the problem on either the safari beta or latest chrome on OSX - I do see the ender logo occasional jump down to mid screen though in safari.

Comment: Steps to reproduce are simply: Go to page, scroll down, scroll back up. I have 10+ reports for Chrome 29.0.x, most on OSX - I've tried using things other then .addClass now, like the HTML5 classList.add()

Comment: Did that - can't repro.  Perhaps someone else will have more luck.

Comment: Possibly. It seems to be intermittent on what it likes to act up on; I have Chrome 27.x 28.x 29.x and 30.x, and Safari reports...

Comment: @KsaRedFx: reproducible on my end, 28.0.1500.95 m.  No duplicate div in the DOM though.

Comment: Yea, upon further digging it appears to be an issue with WebKit artifacting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, Webkit based browsers (Chrome included) have a slightly bugged tile-based renderer, that will fail if there are too many Renter-Tree reflows in a certain span of time.

The particular artifacting i was getting was due to the renderer being unable to handle the number of Render-Tree updates I had going on. Scrolling causes a lot of these.

My workaround was to simply inspect the page with the "Timeline" feature and the "Show Painted Areas" option on, and watch for what was updated the most, then trim it back in other areas of the page, to reduce Reflows.

And, it seems there was a almost a year old bug for this issue; I've provided my information for it and have helped them along with fixing it for future developers http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=151734

Answer (score 1):

I had the same bug with Chrome as well (Windows 7).
The element getting `position:fixed` on scroll got duplicated: one stays fixed and the other scrolls.

In my case, it happened because I had an element with the `transform` property above in the code.

**fix**: add `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` on the element that duplicates (the fixed element)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the browser is having a problem switching back from `position:fixed` when you remove the active class. Try adding `position:static` to your css for the .menu.user class

Sorry, didn't spot the position absolute that you had set. The common fix for webkit artefacts is adding a  `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0)` style. A bit like the old `zoom:1` fix for IE, doesn't change the appearance but forces a redraw.

```
.menu.user {
  width: 226px;
  height: 64px;
  position:absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

Comment: Using position:static; breaks the page in bad ways.

Comment: Really? It does the job in the web inspector, position:static is the default for page elements, so all we're doing is making sure it returns to its original state when the active class is removed.

Comment: Using position:static; pushes all the elements it floats on top of to below it, causing undesirable effects. If you have a workaround for pushing the other elements down, please let me know

Comment: @KsaRedFx sorry didn't spot your position:absolute, try the webkit-transform style (I've edited the answer)

Comment: I've tried the -webkit-transform method already, that did nothing.